# Getting the date the maximum effect happened CausalImpact R

Tags: r, time-series

Using CausalImpact in R

When i use 
  max(impact$series$point.effect) it returns the max effect, 
like so

```
    >     max(impact$series$point.effect)
[1] 4.147952
```

I was wondering if there is a simple way to also get the date associated with this number. Something that would give me an output like 
[1] 4.147952 , 2/14/2017
 any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways with which you can do that, the simplest way is to convert the data into a data-frame and deal with it easily.

I did not try to use additional packages i.e. tidyverse and only used Base R so as not to complicate the solution.

Also I have reproduced an example using MarketMatching data;

```
library(MarketMatching)
library(CausalImpact)

data(weather, package="MarketMatching")
mm <- best_matches(data=weather,
                   id_variable="Area",
                   date_variable="Date",
                   matching_variable="Mean_TemperatureF",
                   parallel=TRUE,
                   warping_limit=1, # warping limit=1
                   dtw_emphasis=1, # rely only on dtw for pre-screening
                   matches=5, # request 5 matches
                   start_match_period="2014-01-01",
                   end_match_period="2014-10-01")


results <- MarketMatching::inference(matched_markets = mm,
                                     test_market = "CPH",
                                     end_post_period = "2015-10-01")

series <- as.data.frame(results$CausalImpactObject$series)
series$date <- rownames(series)
series[which.max(series$point.effect), "date"]
# [1] "2014-10-08"
```